# is it possilbe to uiview, detect from pop navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collectionview called "A" inside another collectionView cell,
in collectionView "A"'s cell, there is uiView.

In this uiview I play some animation.

When I click collectionView "A"'s cell, It pushes navigation controller, and I stop the animation.

I want to play animation again when I pop navigation controller.

Is it possibe to uiview, detect when view is appear again?

I know uiviewcontroller has viewdidload or viewwillapper to detect, but i need uiview to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll have to keep a weak reference of that cell and you can access the specific view when you pop the view controller.
2. Save the index you clicked and get that specific cell using this line and play the animation collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath)

Comment: could you explain more about first approach?

Comment: var customCell: YourCustomCell? = nil

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
customCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    }
Now you have the weak reference stored in your controller
When you pop your controller call customCell.animationView.playAnimation()